# Poisson process - 2D

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, stochastic-processes, poisson-process

> Points are distributed over a 2-D plane, except in a circle of radius $r_0$ centered at the origin, according to a homogeneous Poisson point process with density $\lambda$. Prove:
>   $$\exists c_0:\lim_{\lambda\to \infty}\mathbb{P}\left(\sum_{d_k>r_0}\frac{1}{d_k^\alpha}>\lambda c_0\right)=0$$
>   where $d_k$ is the distance between the $k^{th}$ point & origin, and $\alpha>2$.

**My effort:**

\begin{align}
\lim_{\lambda\to \infty}\mathbb{P}\left(\sum_{d_k>r_0}\frac{1}{d_k^\alpha}>\lambda c_0\right)\stackrel{(1)}{=}\mathbb{P}\left(\lim_{\lambda\to \infty} \frac{1}{\lambda }\sum_{d_k>r_0     }\frac{1}{d_k^\alpha}>c_0\right)
&=\mathbb{P}\left(\lim_{\lambda\to \infty} \frac{1}{\lambda}\sum_{\{d_k>r_0\} \cap \{d_k<\lambda\}     }\frac{1}{d_k^\alpha}> c_0\right)\\
&\stackrel{(2)}{=}\lim_{\lambda\to \infty} \mathbb{P}\left( \sum_{\{d_k>r_0\} \cap \{d_k<\lambda\}     }\frac{1}{d_k^\alpha}>\lambda c_0\right)\\
 \end{align}

How can I prove $(1)$ and $(2)$? If I prove them, I can continue from the last step and complete the proof. Please leave any useful comments.

Comment: Do you mean that it's a conditional distribution by "expect in a circle"?

Comment: @AlexFrancisco I wrote "except" in a circle and I meant there is no point whose distance to the origin is less than $r_0$. I think the memorylessness of the Poisson process makes the distribution unconditional.

Comment: Then, of course, you don't need the condition $d_k>r_0$ in your sum.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The condition $d_k>r_0$ is actually necessary. Because : $E[\sum 1/d_k^α]=c_1 \lambda^{\alpha2}$. In other words, the sum without that condition is on the order of $\lambda^{\alpha/2}$

Comment: If the Poison process lives, as you assume, outside the ball of radius $r_0$, then the sums are equal. Anyway, the question is not about this; do ask if you have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ideas seem to lead nowhere. Even leaving aside the correctness of (1), its right-hand side implicitly assumes that the Poisson processes are given on the same probability space (how exactly?).

So I will give some ideas, which you, hopefully, will be able to elaborate.

Denote by $\Pi_\lambda$ a Poisson point process in $\mathbb R^2$ with intensity $\lambda$, a random measure of the form $\Pi_\lambda = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \delta_{x_\lambda(n)}$, where $\{x_\lambda(n), n\ge 1\}$ are your Poisson points.

> **Theorem.** For any integrable function $f$, 
>   $$
> \lambda^{-1}\int_{\mathbb R^2} f(x) \Pi_\lambda(dx)\to \int_{\mathbb{R}^2}f(x) dx, \ \lambda\to \infty, \tag{1}
> $$
>   in probability.

*Proof* The convergence $(1)$ is easy to see for indicators of bounded sets (e.g. by Chebyshev or LLN). By linearity, it extends to simple functions with bounded support.

Now for arbitrary integrable $f$ let $(f_n,n\ge 1)$ be a sequence of simple functions with bounded support such that $\int_{\mathbb{R^2}} |f_n(x) - f(x)|dx \to 0$, $n\to\infty$.

Now write for any $\varepsilon>0$
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\left|\lambda^{-1}\int_{\mathbb R^2}f(x) \Pi_\lambda(dx) - \lambda^{-1}\int_{\mathbb R^2}f_n(x)dx\right|>\varepsilon \right)\\
\le \mathbb{P}\left(\left|\lambda^{-1}\int_{\mathbb R^2}f_n(x) \Pi_\lambda(dx) - \lambda^{-1}\int_{\mathbb R^2}f_n(x)dx\right|>\frac\varepsilon2 \right)\\ + \mathbb{P}\left(\left|\lambda^{-1}\int_{\mathbb R^2}\big(f(x)-f_n(x)\big) \Pi_\lambda(dx)\right|>\frac\varepsilon2 \right). \tag{2}
$$ 
Using Markov inequality, estimate
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\left|\lambda^{-1}\int_{\mathbb R^2}\big(f(x)-f_n(x)\big) \Pi_\lambda(dx)\right|>\frac\varepsilon2 \right) \\\le \frac2{\varepsilon\lambda}\mathbb{E}\left[\left|\int_{\mathbb R^2}\big(f(x)-f_n(x)\big) \Pi_\lambda(dx)\right|\right]
 \le \frac2\varepsilon \int_{\mathbb R^2}|f(x)-f_n(x)\big|dx.
$$
Finally, first let  $\lambda \to \infty$ in $(2)$ and then $n\to\infty$, arriving at the desired statement.

Comment: Many thanks. I am reading it.

Comment: Thanks. Where does Fact 1 come from? Can you give a reference or a proof?

Comment: Why $f(x)$ not being continuous is not a problem when using Fact 1?

Comment: I don't understand why the inequality above the word "estimating" is true. This is like saying $P(C)\leq P(A)+P(B)$ when $A \cap B \subset C$ which is not necessarily true.

Comment: Also, can you please do the last step accurately and clearly? I cannot understand how you came up with this upperbound.

Comment: @Susan_Math123, I've rewritten the answer. I wrote it somewhat sketchy, intentionally  - try to fill the gaps you see yourself.

Comment: I really appreciate that. But, it would be more beneficial for me if you add more details. I can learn more from it if it is a complete answer.

Comment: I completely disagree with "more benificial". Sorry, I am a hardcore teacher. Come on, try to complete it yourself; I won't do that. I've really written more than I allow myself usually.

Comment: Again, thank you. Can you give me a reference to read, which you think it helps me to learn how to fill the gaps and understand your approach?

Comment: And, if you have videos of your lectures teaching probability, available to public, can you tell me where I can see them?

Comment: Sorry, no videos. I have just lecture notes - in Ukrainian. Concerning the reading, there is a lot of nice texts in advanced probability. Try Sheldon Ross or Durrett.

Comment: Hi, thanks again for your proof.  The theorem you have proved looks like a famous theorem. Does it have a name? Is that special case of a famous theorem?

Comment: @Susan_Math123, I would call it a special case of the Law of large numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Sketch, rather informal approach:

Let the random variable $X_{R}$ count the points inside an annulus, at distances in the interval $[R;R+\Delta R)$ from the origin. Then $X_R$ is a Poisson rv with $E[X_R]=2\pi \lambda R \, \Delta R=Var({X_R})$.

Consider the random variable $$Z=\sum_{k\mid R_k>r_0}\frac{1}{ R_k^\alpha} \approx \sum_{R=r_0}^\infty \frac{X_{R}}{R^\alpha}$$

(The first sum is over all points, the second is over all distances, partitioned at intervals of length $\Delta R$ - the approximation tends to an equality as $\Delta R\to 0$)

Taking the expectation of the last sum:

$$E[Z]=\sum_{R=r_0}^\infty  \frac{E[X_R]}{R_k^\alpha}\to \int_{r_0}^\infty
2\pi \lambda R^{1-\alpha} \, dR =\frac{2 \pi \lambda}{(\alpha-2)r_0^{\alpha-2}}$$

By a similar procedure we can calculate $\sigma_Z^2=Var(Z)$. In general, for independent variables $Y_k$, we have $Z=\sum a_k Y_k \implies \sigma_Z^2 =\sum a_k^2 \sigma_{Y_k}^2$ , hence in our scenario

$$ \sigma_Z^2 =\sum_{R=r_0}^\infty  \frac{Var[X_R]}{R_k^{2\alpha}}\to \int_{r_0}^\infty
2\pi \lambda R^{1-2\alpha} \, dR=\frac{ \pi \lambda}{(\alpha-1)r_0^{2(\alpha-1)}}$$

Hence the normalized variable $W=\frac{Z}{\lambda}$ has fixed (wrt $\lambda$) mean $\mu_W$ , and vanishing variance: $\sigma^2_W = O(\lambda^{-1})$.

Then, applying Chebyshev inequality, $P(W > c_0) \to 0$ as  $\lambda \to \infty$ as long as $c_0 > \mu_W$.

Comment: Thank you. $R_k$ is the distance of the $k$-th point to the origin?

Comment: I read the proof. Can you please add more details to the proof and make it rigorous? Currently, I cannot completely understand your analysis. It is very abstract.

Comment: Yes, $R_k$ is what you called $d_k$. I would not call this answer as "abstract", rather on the contrary.

Comment: Thank you again. By abstract I meant compact. But, I like it. Can you make it rigorous?

Comment: Hi again, can you make it rigorous? You have equal votes and I have to decide which one to choose as the right answer.

Comment: It also extends to any integrable function, if you count points in some small sets instead of circles. Then it would be very similar to my answer, though I use some tightness argument instead of computing the variance.